# Boost read_until docs

Tags: c++, boost, c-strings, stdstring

I'm pretty much a newbie to Boost in general and Boost Asio more specifically-- I've kind of been thrown into the deep end.  I'm reading the Boost docs and I'm wondering if I've run into a typo in the example. On [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until/overload1.html), under Examples, there's the following:

```
std::string data;
std::string n = boost::asio::read_until(s,
    boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(data), '\n');
std::string line = data.substr(0, n);
data.erase(0, n);
```

I can't get this to compile, and I think it's because `n` should be declared as std::size_t, not std::string -- am I correct in this, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: [The Reference for `read_until` is pretty clear](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html), in that `read_until` only returns a `size_t` from its calling.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Also `std::string::substr` expects `std::size_t` in the second argument.

Comment: Xirema, I am quoting the reference page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a typo in the docs.

Example should be as follows:

```
std::string data;
std::size_t n = boost::asio::read_until(s,
    boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(data), '\n');
std::string line = data.substr(0, n);
data.erase(0, n);
```

Thanks to Xirema and S.M for the confirmation.